# Sansation Light bug in Firefox

Tags: firefox, fonts

I am using the Sansation Light fonts in  my web site and in Firefox, I ve noticed the undesirable effect that the sequences `ff`, `fi`, `fl` render as a square instead.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Disable ligatures to make them show properly. Worked for me.

```
-moz-font-feature-settings: "liga" off;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/font-feature-settings